# How to stop being visible to others in Whatsapp after deleting my account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, accounts

I have deleted my whatsapp account and application. Still my friends see my account, they believe I am still on and keep sending messages which never reach me. How to delete my account in such a way my friends no longer see me?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [this link](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/21119703/?category=5245246), It's easy.

Open Whatsapp Application and tap the **Menu Button > Settings > Account > Delete my account**. Write your number and **Delete account**.

Important if you delete account:

> - Delete your account from WhatsApp.
> - Erase your message history.
> - Delete you from all of your WhatsApp groups.
> - **Delete your Google Drive backup.**